# Office.Interop.Word: How to add a picture to document without getting compressed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-word, office-interop

How can I add a picture to a word document without loosing quality using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` assembly?

The common way to insert a picture to word document is:

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
Range docRange = wordDoc.Range();

string imageName = @"c:\temp\win10.jpg";
InlineShape pictureShape = docRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imageName);

wordDoc.SaveAs2(@"c:\temp\test.docx");
wordApp.Quit();
```

This way compresses the picture.

There are optional `LinkToFile` and `SaveWithDocument` parameters but the saved image is compressed and a link is not wanted because picture file mustn't exist externally.

For Excel there is the [`Shapes.AddPicture2` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture2) with `MsoPictureCompress` parameter which seems to be for this. But I cannot find any equivalent for Word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far I have only found a workaround for this issue:

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
Range docRange = wordDoc.Range();

string imagePath = @"c:\temp\win10.jpg";

// Create an InlineShape in the InlineShapes collection where the picture should be added later
// It is used to get automatically scaled sizes.
InlineShape autoScaledInlineShape = docRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath);
float scaledWidth = autoScaledInlineShape.Width;
float scaledHeight = autoScaledInlineShape.Height;
autoScaledInlineShape.Delete();

// Create a new Shape and fill it with the picture
Shape newShape = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
newShape.Fill.UserPicture(imagePath);

// Convert the Shape to an InlineShape and optional disable Border
InlineShape finalInlineShape = newShape.ConvertToInlineShape();
finalInlineShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

// Cut the range of the InlineShape to clipboard
finalInlineShape.Range.Cut();

// And paste it to the target Range
docRange.Paste();

wordDoc.SaveAs2(@"c:\temp\test.docx");
wordApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft documentation [2002066](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2002066/loss-of-image-quality-after-you-save-in-word-excel-or-powerpoint-2007) you can add the following DWORD entry...

```
AutomaticPictureCompressionDefault = 0
```

...to the following registry keys:

For PowerPoint:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

For Word:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options
```

For Excel:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options
```

This still works in Office 2019/Office 365 (You need to change `12.0` to `16.0` then). However, all future documents will not compress any images! This may result in very large file sizes!

Answer (score 0):

Add Images To Docx:

```
    private void ImageToDocx(List<string> Images)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
            Range docRange = wordDoc.Range();

            float mHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= Images.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                // Create an InlineShape in the InlineShapes collection where the picture should be added later
                // It is used to get automatically scaled sizes.
                InlineShape autoScaledInlineShape = docRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Images[i]);
                float scaledWidth = autoScaledInlineShape.Width;
                float scaledHeight = autoScaledInlineShape.Height;
                mHeight += scaledHeight;
                autoScaledInlineShape.Delete();

                // Create a new Shape and fill it with the picture
                Shape newShape = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, scaledWidth, mHeight);
                newShape.Fill.UserPicture(Images[i]);

                // Convert the Shape to an InlineShape and optional disable Border
                InlineShape finalInlineShape = newShape.ConvertToInlineShape();
                finalInlineShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

                // Cut the range of the InlineShape to clipboard
                finalInlineShape.Range.Cut();

                // And paste it to the target Range
                docRange.Paste();
            }

            wordDoc.SaveAs2(@"c:\temp\test.docx");
            wordApp.Quit();
}
```